# Poincarè inequality in dimension $n=1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, functional-inequalities

I have some problem on the following exercise:

Compute the smallest constant $C>0$ such that:

\begin{equation*}
\bigg(\int_{[0,1]}u(x)dx\bigg)^2\leq C\int_{[0,1]}u'(x)^2dx
\end{equation*}

$\forall u\in H^1_0(0,1)$. Compute also all the function such that the inequality with the optimal constant becomes an equality.

Hint: a primitive of $1$ is $x+k$ with $k\in\mathbb{R}$, use Holder inequality and optimize $k$.

First part of the proof:
I first notice that:
\begin{equation*}
u(x)\leq|u(x)|=|u(x)-u(0)|=\bigg\lvert\int_0^x u'(t)dt\bigg\lvert \leq \int_0^1|u'(x)|dx=\|u'\|_{L^1}
\end{equation*}
Now integrating both sides I obtain:
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 u(x)dx\leq \|u\|_{L^1}\leq\int_0^1\|u'\|_{L^1}dx=\|u'\|_{L^1}
\end{equation*}
Using Holder inequality I get:
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1|u'(x)|dx\leq\bigg(\int_0^1 1^2 dx\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(\int|u'(x)|^2 dx\bigg)^{1/2}=\bigg(\int_0^1 1^2 dx\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(\int u'(x)^2 dx\bigg)^{1/2}
\end{equation*}

where the last follows because we are in dimension $n=1$. Combining now the last two term and squaring both sides I get:

\begin{equation*}
\bigg(\int_0^1 u(x)dx\bigg)^2\leq\bigg(\int_0^1 1dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_0^1 u'(x)^2dx\bigg)
\end{equation*}

But from this computation I only find $C=1$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272295/proving-poincare-in-one-dimension)?

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for because I need to compute the optimal constant

Comment: You can read the answer more carefully -- it shows a road how to get the optimal constant. Or, read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360670/estimating-poincare-constant-for-unit-interval)

Comment: I read them carefully and I have a question: why in the second link the infimum is taken on the set of function with $L^2$-norm equal to $1$?

Comment: Because Poincare's inequality is scaling invariant. If you replace $u(x)$ by $cu(x)$ for some constant $c$, then both sides of the inequality get scaled by the same factor $c$.

Comment: Ok and what about my computation? How can I improve it?

Comment: Look at the answer in my first link. It shows a simple way to improve it -- although not the optimal constant yet. To get the obtain constant, as the answer suggests, you can look at the Fourier transform. The second link suggests the Sturm-Liouville Problem, which is also solved by Fourier series.

Comment: Ok but since I'm interested in the second part can you help me with the computation because in your they consider a more regular case $f\in C^\infty$